# Trim Double to 2 decimal places

Tags: java

should be an easy one.  I originally was gonna do this in javascript but have to do it prior to setting to the form in my handler page.  Anyway I need to make these values have 2 decimal places.  Ex 219333.5888888 needs to be 219333.58.  Is there a trim function or something?

```
 form.setUnitRepairCost(Double.toString(jobPlanBean.getUnitTotalCost()));   //UNIT REPAIR COST
 form.setUnitMaterialCost(Double.toString(jobPlanBean.getUnitTotalMaterialCost())); //UNIT MATERIAL COST
```

Comment: * 100, cast to int, divide by 100.0?

Comment: haha..it is the first one...nice

Answer (score 66, accepted):

here is the simple example to format the decimal value

```
import java.text.*;

public class DecimalPlaces {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double d = 1.234567;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        System.out.print(df.format(d));
    }

}
```

Comment: What if you want the number as a double still? Just convert it back?

Comment: Hmm actually this doesn't work since DecimalFormat does rounding. API says - "DecimalFormat provides rounding modes defined in RoundingMode for formatting. By default, it uses RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN". You'd have to change the rounding mode to do that. Or you could DecimalFormat to one more decimal place and then cut it off in the String after formatting. Terrible. Anything that isn't a kludge?

Comment: Why this is the accepted answer? The original question was "219333.5888888 needs to be 219333.58".. but this given solution (as @mikato wrotes right) leads to 219333.59. DecimalFormat.setRoundingMode() needs to be set to RoundingMode.FLOOR;

Comment: @phil That's only correct for positive numbers, as `RoundingMode.FLOOR` doesn't "cut off" negative ones. With 219333.5888888 you get 219333.58, as asked by OP, but -219333.5888888 turns into -219333.59. Use `RoundingMode.DOWN`, that always rounds towards 0 (see table [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html)).

Comment: Good point @Neph , and in my opinion it's not the best answer. Instead we can use casting like bellow:
`double d = -219333.5888888;  d = (double) ((long) (d * 100)) / 100;`

Answer (score 19):

multiply the double by 100.0 and cast this to an int then take that int and cast it to a double and divide by 100.0

```
    int temp = (int)(longDouble*100.0);
    double shortDouble = ((double)temp)/100.0;
```

Comment: Fast and easy to remember.
Mine solution is 
value = ((double)((int)(value *100.0)))/100.0;

Answer (score 13):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        double d = 6.3546;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        System.out.print(df.format(d));
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For getting a double back and not a string:

```
double d = 80.123;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
double p = Double.parseDouble(df.format(d));
```

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat("0.00").format( yourNumber );
```

Comment: Or the link given by TheStijn.

Answer (score 2):

Here is String manipulation to truncate double value up to tow decimal places.

```
public static String truncateUptoTwoDecimal(double doubleValue) {
    String value = String.valueOf(doubleValue);
    if (value != null) {
        String result = value;
        int decimalIndex = result.indexOf(".");
        if (decimalIndex != -1) {
            String decimalString = result.substring(decimalIndex + 1);
            if (decimalString.length() > 2) {
                result = value.substring(0, decimalIndex + 3);
            } else if (decimalString.length() == 1) {
                result = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f",
                        Double.parseDouble(value));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer , as the other approaches does not clear it that what about number of digits before dot.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by other you can use class `DecimalFormat` of `java.text.DecimalFormat`. We can also use `DecimalFormat` to round off decimal values.

Example:

```
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class DecimalDemo {

    private static DecimalFormat decimalFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double number = 2.14159265359;
        System.out.println("Original Number : " + number);
        System.out.println("Upto 2 decimal : " + decimalFormatter.format(number));  //2.14

        // DecimalFormat, default is RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN
        decimalFormatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
        System.out.println("Down : " + decimalFormatter.format(number));  //2.14

        decimalFormatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);
        System.out.println("Up : " + decimalFormatter.format(number));    //2.15

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into using a Decimal Format :

`DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static double truncateDecimals(double d, int len) {
    long p = pow(10, len);
    long l = (long)(d * p);
    return (double)l / (double)p;
}

public static long pow(long a, int b) {
    long result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++) {
       result *= a;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

By using those two methods you can handle all the exceptions also :

```
private String convertedBalance(String balance){
    String convertedBalance = balance.toString();
    Double d;
    try {`enter code here`
        d = Double.parseDouble(balance.toString());
        Log.i("ConvertedNumber", "d (amount) = "+d.toString());
        d = round(d, 2);

        DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        convertedBalance = f.format(d);

        Log.i("ConvertedNumber", "convertedBalance = "+convertedBalance);

    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        Log.i("ConvertedNumber", "Number format exception");
    }

    return convertedBalance;
}


public static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
    bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DecimalFormat: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/FormatNum.html

Answer (score 0):

[DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) Class

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `String.format()` as below.

```
double height = 175.8653;
System.out.println("Height is: " + String.format("%.2f", height));
```

This will trim the double value to two decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using BigDecimal to truncate precision on a double as this will maintain the type as numeric rather than as a string like a formatter would.

```
Double myDouble = 10.12345;
int precision = 3;
MathContext mathContext = new MathContext(precision, RoundingMode.DOWN);
myDouble = new BigDecimal(myDouble, mathContext).doubleValue();
```