# Get number double with some number after "."

Tags: java, double

I have a number double 
`num=35.6923507390297833`
I only want to get number: num=35.692350
How must i do.

Comment: Come on google a bit... "round double java"

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8137281/1585082

Comment: Do you get the number as a `String` or as a `Double`? I suppose you goal is to have it as a string with a certain number digits after the period, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DecimalFormat`

```
double value = ....
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###.######");
String output = myFormatter.format(value);
System.out.println(value);
```

The `#` sign represents a digit, so we construct a pattern that will match  **exactly** six numbers after the decimal point.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) you can read more about Customizing Formats in Java.

Answer (score 1):

you need to take that number as BigDecimal

for Ex:-

BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(35.6923507390297833);
bd.setScale(0,6);

setscale allows you to fix point decimal number.

Answer (score -1):

**double num = 35.6923507390297833;
    num = Precision.round(num, 6);**