# trim values of type Exponential type which are retrieved from ResultSet .getDouble() in java

Tags: java, jdbc, double-precision

I get my values into list from `Resultset.getDouble()`.The values retrieved are of exponential type such as `9.191152283705151E-10` and some values are `89.98999786376953` type.

I want exponential values to be trimmed as 9.191E-10 and other values up to two decimals.

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Comment: what about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137218/trim-double-to-2-decimal-places

Comment: How to trim in a jsp page . My value represented as <td scope="row" style="${r.beam_energy-row.beam_energy eq 0 ? 'background-color: green':'background-color: red'}"><c:out value="${r.beam_energy-row.beam_energy}" ></c:out></td>                                                                                                          SUbtraction of both the Arraylsit represented in JSP page.

Comment: The values returned by `ResultSet.getDouble()` aren't of 'exponential type'. They are *`doubles.`* What you're seeing is the result of *subsequent formatting,` which you haven't shown us.

Comment: @EJP The values present in the database are itself in exponential form.

Comment: Define 'exponential form'. What is the actual column type? While you're at it, define 'exponential values' and 'other values'. You're mentioning data types unknown to computer science, and you're also contradicting yourself.

Comment: @EJP actual column type are **REAL**

Comment: Exactly as I said. It isn't in 'exponential form' at all. `REAL` is a floating-point representation. This is a data formatting problem. You need to post the code that does that.

Answer (score 2):

> I get my values into list from Resultset.getDouble().The values retrieved are of exponential type such as 9.191152283705151E-10 and some values are 89.98999786376953 type.

These are not 'types'. These are *representations.* They are neither present in the database nor created by `ResultSet.getDouble().` According to your comment, the database column is in REAL format, which is floating-point, and the type returned by `ResultSet.getDouble()` is a `double,` which is also floating-point.

These representations are created by some subsequent data formatting step which you haven't shown us: possibly an implicit one such as a `toString()` call.

> I want exponential values to be trimmed as 9.191E-10 and other values up to two decimals.

So have a good look at `DecimalFormat.`

But I have a strong suspicion that your requirement may be ambiguous.

Comment: For display purpose only ,I want to trim my values.