# Error: while trying to format decimal output in Java

Tags: java, decimalformat

I am writing [this program](https://pastebin.com/BA97cjMc) as an assignment for school. The program takes input in the form of 'sex' and 'age' from the user, and gives back the average age of all men and/or women.

The program has worked fine up until my mom beta tested it and we found a problem by happenstance. If by any chance the user were to input a number of individuals where the sum of their ages is not divisible by the number of individuals inputted, the output will give an answer with 15 decimal places. 
For example if I input 3 men with the ages 98, 1 and 1, the program divides 100 by 3 and I get the output:

> 33.333333333333336.

So I took to SO to find a solution to this problem, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33288697/4628703) which I implemented in my program like below so that it would trim down the answer to a maximum of 3 decimal places:

```
/*
This method takes two values. The first value is divided by the second value to get the average. Then it trims the
answer to output a maximum of 3 decimal places in cases where decimals run amok.
*/
public static double average (double a, double b){
    double d = a/b;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
    return Double.parseDouble(df.format(d));
```

I wrote the code in the bottom of my program, in its own method, which I call in the main method at lines 76 and 77:

```
// Here we calculate the average age of all the people and put them into their respective variable.
    double yAverage = average(yAge, men);
    double xAverage = average(xAge, women);
```

However. I get this [error message](https://pastebin.com/zva2BR5z) when I try to run the program, and I don't understand the error message. I tried googling the error, but found nothing.
Please keep in mind that I'm a beginner, and I need as simple an answer as anyone can give me.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `33,333` contains inappropriate decimal separator for `Double.parseDouble`.
There's `df.parse` method should accept the string produced by `df.format`

Comment: Somehow in your code 33.33 is getting converted to 33,33 . This is clearly shown in the error. Try to debug and see where the dot is being replaced by comma.

Comment: I would not do that, its kind of mixing internal and external representation. I would leave the `double` value as precise as possible and just change the output/display so it is formatted as needed/wanted

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your program returning a number with whatever number of digits after the dot. That is the most precise representation of the average. Don't mess with it. What you need to do is *print* it with fewer decimal places. So when you present your dialog box, use `String.format` or `DecimalFormat.format` to print it. That's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) honors you `Locale` setting, formatting the number according to your language setting.

E.g. in US English the result is `33.333`, but in Germany the result is `33,333`.

However, [`Double.parseDouble(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-) is hardcoded to only parse US English formatting.

A few options to fix it:

- Don't round the value. ***Recommended***

  Use a `DecimalFormat` wherever the value needs to be displayed, but keep the full precision of the value itself.
- Force `DecimalFormat` to use US English formatting symbols.

  ```
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.US));
  ```
- Use the `DecimalFormat` to re-parse the value.

  ```
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
  try {
      return df.parse(df.format(d)).doubleValue();
  } catch (ParseException e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e.toString(), e);
  }
  ```
- Don't convert to/from string to round to 3 decimal places.

  - Use [`Math.round(double a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-).

    ```
    return Math.round(d * 1000d) / 1000d;
    ```
  - Use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) *(and stick with it)*. ***Recommended***

    ```
    return BigDecimal.valueOf(d).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    ```
  - Use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) *(temporarily)*.

    ```
    return BigDecimal.valueOf(d).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
    ```

Comment: I'm trying to use the middle of the three lower ones, BigDecimal (and stick with it)
But I get an error message saying that my doubles are not compatible with BigDecimals.

Comment: @ravinki "Stick with it" means that you change the return type to `BigDecimal` too, and change the caller to use `BigDecimal` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    public static double average(double a, double b) {
    double d = a / b;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(
            "#.###", 
            DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)
    );
    return Double.parseDouble(df.format(d));
}
```

You're using a formatting with the point as decimal separator ("#.###"). Depending on the location where you run your program, the Java runtime uses a different localisation setting, e.g. in Germany, where a comma is used as decimal separator.
When you use `new DecimalFormat("#.###")` the default locale is used to interpret the string `#.###` which may work in some places, but won't in others. Luckily, there is another constructor for DecimalFormat where you can specify what symbols should be used. By using `DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)` as second parameter you specify that you want the English formatting conventions ("." as decimal separator, "," for thousands).